# what is the simplest online payment gateway? other than paypal

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal

Or maybe paypal is the most useful of them all.??

to be integrated in asp.net c#

Comment: Only a comment, because who's to say what is simplest if you haven't used them all. But I found Authorize.Net to be fairly easy to work with.

Comment: Depends which payment methods you require ...

Comment: Are you using a commercial shopping cart, or did you build your own?

Comment: [PayPal is utterly hideous; Realex is quite nice](http://timothy.green.name/blog/2013/01/tentative-thoughts-on-payment-gateways/).

Answer (score 3):

I belive **Paypal is the cheapest** (or almost the cheapest).
Along with the cheap fees, PayPal were the 1st (or almost the 1st) to come out on the web as online payment system. IMHO thus PayPal is so widespread!

All the other accounts in the answers are almost as simple to use as PayPal.

But let's look at FEES

- Paypal >> [2.9% + $0.30](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_display-receiving-fees-outside&countries=)
- Google chekout [(same fees of Paypal - click on "Costs and fees")](https://checkout.google.com/sell/?gl=IT&hl=en)
- Moneybookers >> [2.9% + €0.29](https://www.moneybookers.com/app/help.pl?s=m_fees&l=EN) (EURO it's not an error, so watch out)
- AlertPay >> [4.9% + €0.25](https://www.alertpay.com/en/fees.aspx)
- 2checkout >> [5.5% + $0.45 + one time only fee of $49](http://www.2checkout.com/blog/category/getting-started/fees)
- Amazon >> don't know took me too much too look for it (too bad for them)

**Once agin it shows up that prices are a huge marketing axe on the web, much more than in real life.**

And to answer to your 2nd question, C# .net integration does not matter here, all these payment gateway can be integarted with just some HTML code in your site.

Answer (score 2):

[Google Checkout](https://checkout.google.com/main)

Comment: API Reference: https://code.google.com/apis/checkout/samplecode.html

Answer (score 0):

I say that moneybookers is also used a lot and its simple.

http://www.moneybookers.com

Maybe in the future google checkout maybe is also good, but for the moment is very limited.

More to check out
http://sbs.smallbusiness.yahoo.com/merchant/
http://www.2checkout.com/
http://www.saftpay.com/
http://www.alertpay.com/

Answer (score 0):

[Amazon Checkout](https://payments.amazon.com/sdui/sdui/business/overview) is fairly simple to work with.

Answer (score 0):

If you’re based in the UK or Ireland, [Sage Pay](http://www.sagepay.com/) is a solid, reliable and recognisable name to go with.

Answer (score 0):

Plimus.com is easy to use.